# How do I make nvidia-settings work on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, nvidia-graphics-card

I've got two GPUs, and installed nvidia-driver as suggested in Debian Wiki. They appear to be installed normally:

```
keddad@keddad-pc:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 418.74 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: modesetting,nouveau,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 18.3.6 

keddad@keddad-pc:~$ sudo dkms status
nvidia-current, 418.74, 4.19.0-5-amd64, x86_64: installed
```

But when I launch nvidia-settings to change GPU, I face an error:

```
keddad@keddad-pc:~$ sudo -H nvidia-settings 

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

What can I try to fix the issue?

Comment: If you have Secure Boot enabled the driver won't load.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia it is disabled

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're also using Bumblebee to manage Optimus. If you have primus you can run

```
 optirun nvidia-settings -c :8
```

To show nvidia-settings

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/6hoop9/how_to_access_nvidia_settings_when_using/